# How to enable 3D-Secure 2 in Braintree drop-in

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox, 3d-secure

I'm trying to implement 3D-Secure 2.0 with `"braintree-web-drop-in": "1.19.0"`. I went through the braintree docs for 3D secure and dropin-ui, but couldn't find a way to specify version of 3D secure to be used.

I tried passing in `version:2` at different levels while creating the dropin.

1.

```
authorization: clientToken,
container: '#dropin-container',
version: 2,
threeDSecure: {
                  amount: '1'
              },
```

2.

```
authorization: clientToken,
container: '#dropin-container',
threeDSecure: {
                  amount: '1',
                  version: 2
              },
```

3.

```
authorization: clientToken,
container: '#dropin-container',
threeDSecure: {
                options: {
                        version: 2
                    },
                    amount: '1'
                },
```

None of these worked. Its always using version 1.

The `/three_d_secure/lookup` call has `threeDSecureVersion:"1.0.2"`

I am not getting the error 'THREEDS_NOT_ENABLED_FOR_V2' either. So 3D secure 2 must be enabled already for my sandbox account.

Do i have to manually enable anything in my Sandbox and production Braintree accounts?
Does it take version 1 as the default? How do i make it use version 2?

Comment: ```authorization: clientToken,
container: '#dropin-container',
threeDSecure: {
                  amount: '1',
                  version: 2
              }, ``` worked. The problem was with the test card that i was using. None of the test cards mentioned in https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/php has 3D secure 2 enabled. The ones in https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/3d-secure/migration/javascript/v3 have it enabled.